# C# Breaking up a DateTime with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

I have a value that is stored as a DateTime.

In order to make the output look more readable in an export, I would like to only have the MM/DD returned from the expression.

My current solution involves passing the DateTime as a string to a function which effectively chops it up into small pieces, and puts it back together again.  While this works, I know that there must be a more effective/elegant solution.

My current code looks like this:

```
extractDate(DateTimeVar.ToString());
```

And the definition:

```
    private string extractDate(string datetime)
    {
        string[] newString = datetime.Split(' ');
        string newStringArray = newString[0];
        string[] breakUp = newStringArray.Split('/');
        string finalOutput = breakUp[0] + "/" + breakUp[1];
        return finalOutput;
    }
```

As you can see, quite messy.  Another solution I came up with involved chopping off the first five characters, since a DateTime's first 5 characters will always include "MM/dd":

```
    private string extractDate(string datetime)
    {
        return datetime.Substring(0, 5);
    }
```

I would assume that the latter solution is a better one.  However, is there one that is even better?  Thanks.

Comment: In retrospect, my 2nd solution was useless as well - a DateTime with a single digit month or day value would cause bad output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use:

```
DateTimeVar.ToString("MM/dd");
```

There is no need for a custom method, as [`DateTime.ToString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) already allows [custom format strings for DateTime values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Perfect solution.  I knew there was something obvious I was missing, but did not know ToString() was capable of this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use the [ToString(formatThatYouWant)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) override?

The code would be:

```
.ToString("MM/dd");
```

Remember, MSDN is your friend :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `DateTimeVar.ToString("MM/dd")` method.

For a full list of options you can pass to the ToString method check the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: "mm" is minutes, "MM" is month

Answer (score 2):

how about  `datetime.ToString("MM/dd")` ?  or datetime.Month and datetime.Day

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for this you can use the `DateTime.ToString(string)` method ro extract what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw

```
datetimevar.ToString("MM/dd");
```

Then you don't need to care about the locale as the output of ToString() with no arguments
depends on your culture i.e the value differs...